# Docker - Unable to locate package docker-engine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, docker-machine, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to install docker in Ubuntu 16.04. I am following [this link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/) for docker installation. I am ending up with **Unable to locate package docker-engine**

My current kernal version - **4.4.0-38-generic**
Ubuntu version - **16.04**

Comment: Did you update your apt sources following instruction here [Update your apt sources](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/#/update-your-apt-sources)

Comment: What output do you get when you execute following: `apt-cache policy docker-engine` in terminal ?

Comment: I had the same problem. Run `sudo apt-get update` and then try again `sudo apt-get install docker-engine` . This solved the issue by me

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The docker package *already inside Ubuntu* is called `docker.io` [1] so just do

```
sudo apt-get install docker.io
```

But *if* you follow that [link you gave](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/) and do steps 7, 8, 9 then your installation will know about the package at the docker repo and also find `docker-engine`.

Your call. I run the Ubuntu version (currently 0.11.2 on Ubuntu 16.04) on some machines, and the one from Docker on others (as I was curious about some 0.12 features).  Both will work just fine.

[1] As `docker` is used for a desktop launcher application 'docking' icons.

Comment: I installed docker.io and the docker is running. I created docker group and added my user to docker group. But when I run `docker run hello-world` , I am ending up with an error **docker: Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = 2 desc = "oci runtime error: exec format error".** The docker is running and active. I restarted docker and even restarted my machine, still no go.

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue on AWS-EC2 with ubuntu-18.04 server...

running **apt-get update** does the trick for me....

Once update runs fine then run **apt-get install docker.io**

Answer (score 2):

Docker-compose-plugin is put into the docker.io repo. 
Running  `sudo apt install docker.io` ,or apt-get in older Ubuntu versions, will also get you the files you need.
 First you will need to run update to make sure you have most recent versions.
 `sudo apt update`

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't able to install docker with the current other solutions but managed to get rid of the "Unable to locate package docker-engine" error with a solution mentioned on the GitHub repo issues (issue of May 31, 2020).

The solution was to run these commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg-agent software-properties-common
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
sudo apt update
sudo apt install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```

Answer (score 1):

The main solution which solved most of the issues in docker is installing 64-bit version of ubuntu. I was running with 32-bit(i686). Hope it helps ! !

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

```
sudo apt install docker-compose
```